# Django URL regex problem

Tags: regex, django

I don't know why i can't match url when url is "http://localhost:8000/home/CPM%201.6.1001"
since i want pass parameter CPM 201.6.1001 from my template to urls
thanks:)

## urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
    (r'^home/(?P<build>\[^/]+)/$', 'views.run'),   
)
```

ps. when i use (r'^home/[^/]+/$', 'views.run') it can work, but i can't use this parameter in my views, below is my views:

## views.py

```
def run(request, build):
    ...
```

i hope get build parameter to present next page.
thanks again:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you have there really the following?

```
(r'^home/(?P<build>\[^/]+)/$', 'views.run')
```

there is an excessive backslash, correct regexp string is:

```
r'^home/(?P<build>[^/]+)/$'
```